# How to fetch data from multiple urls and save it in an array (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of RSS URLs that i would like to get data from and save that data in one array. here is my code:

```
// rss urls array
var URLS = [
  "https://www.wired.com/feed/rss",
  "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml",
  "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss"
];
```

I have a data variable in my state where i would like the data to get stored

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }
```

I use the `fetchData()` function to attempt to fetch the Data

```
  fetchData() {
    var urlArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < URLS.length; i++) {
      urlArray.push(URLS[i]);
    }

    fetch(urlArray)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          data: this.extractData(responseData)
        });
      }).done();
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
```

I use the `extractData` function to get data from the rss feed like this

```
  extractData(text) {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
    var items_array = [];
    var items = doc.getElementsByTagName('item');

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items_array.push({
        title: items[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].lastChild.data,
        description: items[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0].lastChild.data,
        //thumbnail: items[i].getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url'),
        //link: items[i].getElementsByTagName('link')[0].textContent,
        //date: items[i].getElementsByTagName('pubDate')[0].textContent,                    
      })
    }
    return items_array;
  }
```

But when i run i am getting an error saying "cannot load an empty URL"

Comment: you can try `URLS.map(url=> fetch(url).then(res=>res.text()).then(extractData).then(items=> this.setState({data:this.state.data.push(...items)})))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @guest271314 answer, modify the setState call as

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ data: [...prevState.data, this.extractData(responseData)] })
```

In your earlier code you were overwriting the data array every time a request completed. In the above snippet, you can see that it's adding the new response to the previous array.

Comment: and when i specify the index its showing only 3 items on the list `this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ data: [...prevState.data, this.extractData(responseData)[0]] })`

Comment: Thanks i managed to fix the issue i had to do it like this: `data: [...prevState.data, ...this.extractData(responseData)]`

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an array to `fetch()` instead of a string or `Request` object. You can use `Promise` all or `async/await` and a loop to make multiple calls to `fetch()` and get result when all requests complete or log error if any other the requests throw an error. You can also handle the error and continue the loop to get both successful requests and error messages.

```
  fetchData() {    
    return Promise.all(
      URLS.map(url => 
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(responseData => {
          this.setState({
            data: this.extractData(responseData)
          })
        })
        .catch(err => /* handle errors here */ console.error(err))
      )
    ).then(() => {// do stuff}, err => {// handle error})
  }
```

It is not clear from Question what `.done()` is or what the expected result of calling `.done()` is.

Comment: All the requests are being fetched now, but they seem to override the previous data instead of adding all of it into the array.

Comment: That is probably related to reactjs code at `this.setState({
            data: this.extractData(responseData)
          })`, which have limited experience using.

Comment: What is the expect result of `data` at `this.setState({
            data: this.extractData(responseData)
          }`?